# how to remove /u00 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some values like `/u0082` `/u008b` ...etc how to remove it from my string

```
var pattern = /\b/u00\b/g;
var newString = myString.replace(pattern,' ');
```

I tried something like this but it did not work and display Illegal token

Comment: can you post your total text contents

Comment: you can use like this //u[^/]+/g

Comment: use (/u\d+)[^/]+ for replace only /u00

Comment: i just want to remove string starts with /u00

Comment: then directly use /u00

Comment: pls post your total myString string

Comment: .  `ฅ/u008aฅ/u0092ฅ/u0082 link mit` it is something like this

Comment: sorry try this myString.replace(/\/u00/g,'')

Answer (score 0):

to replace all /u008a or /u009b. you could use like this.

```
 myString.replace(/\/u00../g,' ')
```

Comment: for example it is just replacing `/u00` of  string `/u008a`  8a remained as it is

Comment: what you want to replace? either /u00 or /uintegers or ?

Comment: i want to replace  whole /u008a,  means   whatever two characters comes after /u00 i want to replace that with space . as /u00 is constant in this but only two characters after /u00 is varying like  /u0082 /u008b /u0092 /u009e so i want to replace /u00**  whole this with space

Comment: you could use like this 'ฅ/u008aฅ/u0092ฅ/u0082'.replace(/\/u00../g, ' ' )

Comment: thanx  @raghavendra for ur valuable time ...to solve my query ..it worked

Comment: @raghavendra Glad that your answer solved the problem. Please add more details to your answer and take care of the typos.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pattern = /\b/u00\b/g;
    var regExpr= /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
    pattern = pattern .replace(regExpr, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
    pattern = unescape(pattern );
    console.log(pattern );
```